# Failed to initialize player and Uncaught (in promise) Web playback sdk Spotify

Tags: javascript, spotify

I refer this tutorial [spotify web playback example](https://glitch.com/~spotify-web-playback), I can get access_token, device_id have have track id already. When I test it on localhost, it works well. But when I deploy to my Ubuntu server (code used on CakePHP project) then it throw errors:

1. {message: "Failed to initialize player"}
2. Uncaught (in promise) n
   {code: "LIST_PLAYER_NO_TRACK_PLAYER", message: "Platform does not
   support navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess"
3. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

This is my js:

```js
// Get the hash of the url
const hash = window.location.hash
    .substring(1)
    .split('&')
    .reduce(function (initial, item) {
        if (item) {
            var parts = item.split('=');
            initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
        }
        return initial;
    }, {});
window.location.hash = '';

// Set token
let _token = hash.access_token;

const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
const clientId = 'my_client_id';
const redirectUri = 'http://'+ location +'/tracks/authorize';
const scopes = [
    'streaming',
    'user-read-birthdate',
    'user-read-private',
    'user-modify-playback-state'
];

console.log("Token: " + _token);

// If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
if (!_token) {
    window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&response_type=token&show_dialog=false`;
}

// Set up the Web Playback SDK

window.onSpotifyPlayerAPIReady = () => {
    const player = new Spotify.Player({
        name: 'Web Playback SDK Template',
        getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(_token); }
    });

    // Error handling
    player.on('initialization_error', e => console.error(e));
    player.on('authentication_error', e => console.error(e));
    player.on('account_error', e => console.error(e));
    player.on('playback_error', e => console.error(e));

    // Playback status updates
    player.on('player_state_changed', state => {
        console.log(state)
        $('#current-track').attr('src', state.track_window.current_track.album.images[0].url);
        $('#current-track-name').text(state.track_window.current_track.name);
    });

    // Ready
    player.on('ready', data => {
        console.log('Ready with Device ID', data.device_id);

        // Play a track using our new device ID
        play(data.device_id);
    });

    // Connect to the player!
    player.connect();
}

// Play a specified track on the Web Playback SDK's device ID
function play(device_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=" + device_id,
        type: "PUT",
        data: '{"uris": ["spotify:track:5ya2gsaIhTkAuWYEMB0nw5"]}',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token );},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

This is my html page:

```js
<h4 style="margin-top: 60px">Successfully grant to play stream from Spotify Web Playback SDK</h4>
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
<?= $this->Html->script('authorize/authorize.js') ?>
```

Comment: For developer who have the same issue to me, we must use Spotify Web Playback SDK in secured context (https), localhost is consider as secured context. link: https://github.com/spotify/web-playback-sdk/issues/2